# The array value changed after calling static method with the array Java

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods

The value of array elements are getting changed while calling a static method with the parameter passing the same array as argument but primitive value does not get changed

Is it work differently in the case of while we pass data structure as method argument ?
Want to know why array element get changed after the method call with the array ..
I was expecting value 0 in the last syso statement instead of 999

```
public class TestStatic {
    
    public static int square (int x)
    {
        x = x + 1;
        return x * x;       
    }

    public static int[] changeArr(int a[])
    {
        a[0] = 999;
        return a;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = 10;

        System.out.println((square(a)));
        System.out.println(a);

        int arr[] = {0,0};
        changeArr(arr);
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Actual Output:

```
121
10
999
```

I was expecting

```
121
10
0
```

Comment: `changeArr(arr)` - `arr` is a reference to an array that you declared inside the `main` method. Since you passed reference to the `changeArr` method, when method changes the value at the first index, it changes the same array that you declared inside `main` method.

Comment: Probably, signature, which can be read as `a[]` item is of type `int`, is misleading a little bit. Change it to: `public static int[] changeArr(int[] a) { ... }`
and read: `a` is a parameter of type `int[]`. So it is an object and objects are pass by reference not by type.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, method parameters are by reference, not by value, which means you pass the reference to the object, not a copy of the object. Note that primitives are passed by value.

Comment: Everything is passed by value. In case of objects, value is the reference to an object.